# Magento2: Save Product Data for global scope using Rest API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am trying to add product using Rest API. Adding product is working fine.

But I am facing issue in assign in the product information only for Default values instead of copying data for store view. When we select store view `Use Default Value` checkbox must be checked. Only one attribute value must save in database with scope 0 instead of copying same values for each store.

How can I achieve the above scenario using Rest API ? Below is what I have tried so far:

**Case 1:**

I tried to call API using the below URL, But It replicate the product values for store view.

```
POST   /rest/V1/products
```

**Case 2:**

I tried to call API using the below URL, But It also replicate the product values for store view.

```
POST   /rest/{store_code}/V1/products
```

**Case 3:**

I tried to call API using the below URL

```
POST   /rest/all/V1/products
```

using the above website not assigned to product. so I called `catalogProductWebsiteLinkRepositoryV1` to assign product in website as below, but it also replicate the product values for store view.

```
POST   /rest/V1/products/{sku}/websites
```

Please suggest how can we save product data for global scope only ?

Note: only have one website, one store and one store view in magento installtion.

Comment: In your POST data try to add store_id  0 (admin store) like you'd do in a Magento 2 code `$product->setStoreId(0); $product->setMyAttribute(123); $product->save();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an acknowledge issue of Magento 2. You can check it over here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8121

The workaround for your case is setStoreId to zero as @obscure commented. You will do it by override ProductRepository or create a composer patch for it.

> app/code/Stackoverflow/Catalog/etc/webapi_rest/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository" type="Stackoverflow\Catalog\Model\Catalog\ProductRepository" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Stackoverflow/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace Stackoverflow\Catalog\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class ProductRepository extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
{
    /**
     * Merge data from DB and updates from request
     *
     * @param array $productData
     * @param bool  $createNew
     *
     * @return ProductInterface|Product
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    protected function initializeProductData(array $productData, $createNew)
    {
        $product = parent::initializeProductData($productData, $createNew);

        // If product is new, we will store all the values on global scope
        if ($createNew) {
            $productId = $product->getId();
            if (!$productId) {
                $product->setStoreId(0);
            }
        }

        return $product;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: During Product update, it again update data in view scope instead of global one. Any idea ?